# Quartz Scheduler for Test Environment not working

Tags: mysql, web-services, rest, tomcat7, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to Web services & creating an email scheduler using "quartz-2.2.1.jar" & "quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar", & deploying war on "apache-tomcat-7.0.57" for both Dev & test Environment, for Dev scheduler is working fine without any problem, but for Test Environment it is changing status from pending to failed with erro message as

"Failed
Error Message :
Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target))",

I tried to swap server & DB but problem remains same, can any one help me to find what exactly is causing problem to Test Environment

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just found this...investigating...

Site ->  https://jquery.com/download/

-- jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x but…

```
...does Not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8
```

Since IE 8 is still relatively common, we recommend using the 1.x version unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8 users are visiting the site. Please read the 2.0 release notes carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to fix this (still working on it)...

...but, I have found that in my environment, this is being caused by a deprecated Attribute (...'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead...).

This is causing the mismatch of information sent to the - synchronous function - processor - in the request sent, which causes the SSLHandshake in the securityValidator to block the request to it's target.

Thus causing the error and failure of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to fix this (still working on it)...

...but, I have found that in my environment, this is being caused by a deprecated Attribute (...'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead...).

This is causing the mismatch of information sent to the - synchronous function - processor - in the request sent, which causes the SSLHandshake in the securityValidator to block the request to it's target.

Thus causing the error and failure of the function.

You might want to check for any deprecated Attributes, hope this helps in some way. 
 - Cheers!